# Swift parsing json, and show to the user issue

Tags: json, swift

I am parsing a JSON on my own, after seeing a couple of tutorials, I try to adapt an OMBD API, but Xcode is throwing me this error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7ca9f68), how do I debug this, below is what I've done so far.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MovieManagerDelegate {

    lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        UILabel()
    }()

    var movieManager = MovieManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        movieManager.delegate = self

        movieManager.performMovieRequest(urlRequest: movieManager.movieUrl)
        viewHierarchy()
        constraitsMaker()
        additionalComponents()
    }

    func viewHierarchy() {
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    }

    func constraitsMaker() {
        titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.center.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    func additionalComponents() {
        titleLabel.textColor = .black
    }

    func didUpdateTitle(movie: MovieModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.titleLabel.text = movie.movieTitle
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
import Foundation

protocol MovieManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateTitle(movie: MovieModel)
}

struct MovieManager {

    let viewController = ViewController()

    let movieUrl = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=b6531970"
    let posterUrl = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM0NTc0NzItM2FlYS00YzEwLWE0YmUtNTA2ZWIzODc2OTgxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgwNzIyNzg@._V1_SX300.jpg"

    var delegate: MovieManagerDelegate?

    func performMovieRequest(urlRequest: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: movieUrl) {           
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data {
                    let movie = self.parseJSON(movieData: safeData)
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateTitle(movie: movie!)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    //parse json function
    func parseJSON(movieData: Data) -> MovieModel? {// with data as a parameter
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        //do try catch to handle errors of decoded json
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MovieData.self, from: movieData)//call the data for decode json. movie data comes from the parameter of the function, that is subclassed as data object
            let title = decodedData.Title

            let movie = MovieModel(movieTitle: title)
            return movie
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

---

```
import Foundation

struct MovieData: Codable {
    let Title: String
    let Year: String
    let Rated: String
    let Writer: String
    let Released: String
    let Runtime: String
    let Genre: String
    let Director: String
    let Actors: String
    let Plot: String
    let Language: String
    let Country: String
    let Awards: String
    let Poster: URL
    let Ratings: [Ratings]
    let Metascore: String
    let `Type`: String
    let DVD: String
    let BoxOffice: String
    let Production: String
}

struct Ratings: Codable {
    let Source: String
    let Value: String


}
```

---

```
import Foundation
struct MovieModel {
    let movieTitle: String
}
```

Comment: On what line does it crash?

Comment: It crashes reliably if an error occurs in `parseJSON`. Don't force unwrap. And read the error message. It tells you what's wrong and where.

Comment: What is the JSON format that you're trying to parse?

Comment: Crashes on the lazy var title label

Comment: The json is on the URL in the movie manager, I trying to do on mvc, also

Answer (score 0):

MovieManager makes an asynchronous call when downloading data meaning the code after the call to performMovieRequest is executed before the data is downloaded and the label has been initialised. It should work fine to move the calls in viewDidLoad to the delegate method

```
func didUpdateTitle(movie: MovieModel) {
    viewHierarchy()
    constraitsMaker()
    additionalComponents()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.titleLabel.text = movie.movieTitle
    }
}
```

If you are calling the delegate method after that as well you might want to have a boolean property to verify the 3 methods from viewDidLoad doesn't get called again